# How to change values json groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have json like this:

```
"tags":[
{"tag":"TAG1","value":"VALUE1"},
{"tag":"TAG2","value":"VALUE2"},
{"tag":"TAG3","value":"VALUE3"},
{"tag":"TAG4","value":"VALUE4"}]
```

Is it possible to change values (VALUE1, VALUE2 etc) to something else instead of current json values?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: yes, it's possible. https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html

Comment: Your JSON is either ill-formed or it's an incomplete snippet. It needs another set of braces `{}` surrounding the whole thing to be well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change values (VALUE1, VALUE2 etc) to something else
> instead of current json values?

Yes.

You could do something like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String jsonInputString = '''
{"tags":[
{"tag":"TAG1","value":"VALUE1"},
{"tag":"TAG2","value":"VALUE2"},
{"tag":"TAG3","value":"VALUE3"},
{"tag":"TAG4","value":"VALUE4"}]}
'''
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonInputString)
json.tags[0].value = 'updated value'
json.tags[1].value = 'another updated value'

println json
```

That will output the following:

```
[tags:[[tag:TAG1, value:updated value], [tag:TAG2, value:another updated value], [tag:TAG3, value:VALUE3], [tag:TAG4, value:VALUE4]]]
```

**Update:**

The requirements aren't clear but if you want to dynamically find the elements you want to update, you could do something like this:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonInputString)
json.tags.find { it.tag == 'TAG1' }?.value = 'updated tag1'
json.tags.find { it.tag == 'TAG2' }?.value = 'updated tag2'
```

Comment: Notice that my input string has curly braces around it and your input does not.  If you have to wrap your string in curly braces then you could use something like `new JsonSlurper().parseText("{${jsonInputString}}")`.